# How to pass django FileField file content to urllib2 for a POST request?

Tags: python, django, post, urllib2, django-storage

I'm trying to create a storage backend for BackBlaze's B2 product. But I can't seem to pass the file properly when calling _save(). All the other conditions are satisfied for the request, api tokens etc.

Here's my code:

```
def b2_upload_file(self, file_name, file_content):
    file_contents = file_content.read()

    sha1_of_file_data = hashlib.sha1(file_contents).hexdigest()
    content_type = getattr(file_contents, 'content_type',mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0] or self.key_class.DefaultContentType)
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : self.upload_auth_token,
        'X-Bz-File-Name' :  file_name,
        'Content-Type' : content_type,
        'X-Bz-Content-Sha1' : sha1_of_file_data
    }
    request = urllib2.Request(self.upload_url, file_contents, headers)

    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_data = json.loads(response.read())
    response.close()
    file_id = response_data['fileId']
    return file_id

def _save(self, name, content):
    self.b2_authorize_account()
    self.b2_get_upload_url()
    file_id = self.b2_upload_file(name, content)
    return file_id
```

Which gives the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/music/track/100/
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)

Unicode error hint
The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: RIFF��WA
```

Caused by:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

Some local_vars:

```
file_content : <FieldFile: fools_gold.wav>
file_name: u'music/fools_gold.wav'
request:<urllib2.Request instance at 0x7f93798a3e18>
sha1_of_file_data: '9bf643c9f2b974221103d796f64dce76ae6b4a08'
headers :{'Authorization': u'2_20151213021507_13c5507f01d49b34ba3a540c_040a04f65efa8a50d4ea8541cf285a3cc3b7d5d8_upld',
 'Content-Type': 'audio/x-wav',
 'X-Bz-Content-Sha1': '9bf643c9f2b974221103d796f64dce76ae6b4a08',
 'X-Bz-File-Name': u'music/fools_gold.wav'}
file_contents: 'RIFF\xa4\xc3\x05\x00WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x88X\x01\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00data\x80\xc3\x05\x00\xc8\xff\xea\xffL\xff\x17\xff\xc2\xff(\x006\x007\x00\xe6\xff\x8d\xff,\xffO\xff\xc1\xff\x0f\xff\xd9\xfe\x07\x00\xf6\xff7\xff\xd1\xff\x0c\x00\x1e\xff\xfb\xfe\x16\x00o\x00\xfa\xff\xce\xff\x88\xffp\xffh\xffe\xff\xf7\xff\xba\x00q\x00\\\xff\xca\xfe\xed\xfe_\xff\x94\xff\x1c\x00\xb5\x00\x92\x00N\x00\x90\x005\x00\n\xff\n\xff\xb2\xffR\xffK\xffn\x00\'\x00\x96\xffn\x00K\x00W\xff\xfa\xff\xb9\x00e\xff\xc5\xff\xc1\x00z\xff}\xff\x04\x00n\xff\xf9\xff\x80\x00M\xfff\x00\x83\x01\x88\xfe+\xfd1\x03\x17\x07\x9c\xfe\x8a\xfaY\x01\x82\x00\xb0\xf9d\xfdc\x05\xf2\x02\xab\xfd\xde\xfd\x83\xff\xe6\x00\x10\x02\xd0\x01y\x00D\x00L\x00t\xffi\xff\x01\x00\xff\xff\x95\x00n\x02\xe0\x01\xac\xfe\xdb\xfe\xa7\x02\xf2\x02\xc6\x00[\xfe\x9e\xfb$\xfb6\xfbj\x00\xd2\x08\xe4\t\x06\x04\xc2\xfc\x12\xf9z\xf9j\xfc\xd9\xff\xbb\x02\x98\x05\xe7\x06Y\x049\xff\xb9\xfd>\xffb\xfdB\xfc^\xff\xbf\x01\xd7\x02\xa6\x02_\x01O\x01\xd8\x01O\x02\x87\x01r\xff\xff\xfe7\x00\xcd\xfe\x8d\xfcb\xfe\x13\x02\x13\x038\x02\xfe\x01A\x02\xcc\x03\x07\x04E\x00\x92\xfdO\xfe\x01\xff\xd6\xff\x97\xff\xa2\xff\x1a\x03\xdb\x02\x8c\xfe\xae\xffB\x03l\x02\xa2\x00=\x00s\x00\xf7\xffh\x00\xc1\x02\xce\x01\xd2\xff\xc2\x00\xd6\x00h\xff\xa1\xfe\x01\x00\xff\x01T\x01\x1a\x02e\x040\x03Z\xff\xc2\xfb\x81\xfc\xd6\x00\xdb\x04z\x06\xd5\x03\x00\x00h\xfev\xfe\xde\xfe\x96\xff\x98\x01_\x03\xb6\x02\xff\x00\x7f\x00U\x01\xbc\x00@\xff\x06\x01q\x02+\x02}\x022\x01\x17\x00\x1c\x00\xc2\xfe\xf9\xfe7\x02\x81\x03:\x02\xe8\xff?\xfe\xef\xff\xa5\x01\xec\xff\xc9\xfe\xd7\x00\xd6\x01\x1d\x03\xcc\x038\x01:\x00\xea\x00\x95\x01\x02\x00\xa6\xfd\xa5\xff\xf2\x01\x92\x00\xd4\xfe\x82\xff\xc1\x01\xd5\x02\xdf\x01\xd9\xff.\x00o\x02\xc5\x02k\x015\x00\xdf\x01\xc0\x02\x89\x00g\xfea\xfe\x13\x01h\x02\x12\x02g\x01L\x01\xa6\x00\x04\xfe\x85\xfe{\x01\xb4\x03\xd7\n\xe3\x17U\x19+\x10z\x10\xbf\x11\xb6\x101\x11i\x0es\r\xc4\n\x93\t\xc0\n\x9c\n\xd7\n\xfc\x05\xaa\x01\x0e\x03\x19\x07\xef\x06q\x05\xa7\x06\xd7\x03\xbd\xfe\x0e\xfb\xb8\xfa\xec\xf9W\xfb\xbb\xfd\t\xfdp\xfe\xec\xff>\xfe\x9e\xfb\x87\xfc\x00\xfe\x91\xfe\xef\xfd\xda\xfb\x94\xfc\x08\x03\xdb\x08A\x07\xeb\x03\xfd\x03F\x01\xf5\xfa\x1c\xfa2\xfb\x1a\xfbf\xfa\x97\xf9\xf6\xfa\xfa\xfck\xfc\t\xf9\x97\xf6^\xf7\xf1\xf6N\xf3"\xf3\x9f\xf5\xa9\xf6\x12\xf6\x1f\xf6\xbf\xf5\x02\xf4B\xf3\x01\xf4\x0b\xf5\x12\xf4\xcf\xf2\xe4\xf1\x99\xf0\x86\xee<\xf0\xcc\xf5P\xf5\xc4\xf2\xd1\xf3 \xf5\xd8\xf6^\xf6\xb3\xf4B\xf5\x7f\xf7\x06\xf9u\xf49\xf0\x84\xf3\xf4\xf68\xf6\xef\xf4\x05\xf6o\xf8\xab\xf7w\xf3\'\xf2\xf0\xf4\x11\xf6\xf1\xf0\xfd\xec\xc0\xf0\x17\xf4N\xf4\xc0\xf3\x85\xf2/\xf1\xa9\xf0\xfc\xf1J\xf2R\xf2\x8f\xf10\xeex\xefU\xf7\xbd\xfd\x10\xfb\xe1\xef\xfe\xe6\xcf\xe8\xa3\xf3\xa2\xffl\x014\xf9\xcb\xef\r\xeb\x86\xec\x1a\xf1\xbc\xfaU\x030\x03d\xfc\x12\xf2\x9d\xeb\xf2\xed\x81\xf6\r\xfc\xe7\xfa>\xf8h\xf8\x99\xfa\xce\xfd\xfe\x05\xed\x0c\xe7\x07\xc2\xfd\xd0\xf7c\xf4\x00\xf3U\xf2g\xf2\x0e\xf8\xa3\x072\x1d8*\xff*^%j\x1c\x88\x11+\n3\x08\xa4\x05\x01\xff\xc1\xf4\xfa\xec\x97\xeb\xa6\xeeH\xf4\xe4\xfc\xe7\x05\x0f\n\r\x08\xd7\x00\xb8\xf9\xd9\xf83\xfb\xae\xfaK\xfa$\xfdI\xff\x8a\x00^\x02i\x03\xaf\x04\x89\x07\xa1\tW\x08[\x08\x19\n\xf5\t\xfb\n\xad\x0b\xc9\x0bB\x0e\x9a\x0eC\x0c9\x0c^\x0e{\x0ej\x0eP\x10\xf1\x0f\x91\x0f\xf1\x0f\x19\x10\xd3\x0f9\x0e^\x0f\xdf\x11\x97\x11\x8a\x0f\x9f\x0eL\x0fa\x0f\xa2\x0e\xff\x0f\xea\x11V\x11q\x0f\xff\x0f=\x12\xd8\x106\x0f8\x10\x10\x12_\x12;\x11i\x10\xea\x0f+\x12\xc5\x13K\x12F\x11\xf7\x11\x8a\x12d\x11\xf5\x11\xb1\x12T\x12]\x137\x13*\x11\x12\x11\xb6\x12\x83\x12\xba\x11\xa7\x10\xfd\x10E\x13\xf7\x12\x97\x11\r\x11\xd4\x11M\x14\xfd\x12B\x0f\xbc\x10\xef\x12\xdd\x10\x1a\x0fA\x11\xda\x13\x82\x12\xff\x10>\x10\x1c\x0e\xb0\x0c\x90\x0cx\x0cQ\rR\x10\x17\x12*\x12$\x12\xcd\x11\xfb\x13\'\x16\x8c\x14\n\x14\x1f\x16\xce\x176\x18+\x18\xb7\x19k\x1a\xa5\x19\xce\x17\xb6\x15\x1a\x15\x15\x12\x95\rJ\n\xa8\x089\tW\x08O\x05\x00\x04q\x05\xbc\x06\x90\x06m\x06\x89\x05\xa6\x05\xef\x07\x95\t\xdb\x0b\x12\x11\xd1\x16\x06\x1bI\x1d\x90\x1c\xa1\x1c\xcd\x1c(\x1bU\x1b\xa5\x1c\x8f\x1c\xe6\x19\xfd\x168\x13F\r\xb3\x08\x10\x06\xeb\x02\x02\xfe=\xfb\xb1\xfa\x14\xf8\xb6\xf4... <trimmed 1281010 bytes string>
content_type: 'audio/x-wav'
```

I'm completely stumped here and have no idea how to pass the file from django to the request. Can anyone help me?

Link to BackBlaze B2 Docs on API call I am trying to use: https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/b2_upload_file.html

**EDIT**

I managed to get files to save to BackBlaze B2 by writing it as a temp file first and borrowing some code for the EnhancedFile class:

```
class EnhancedFile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keyws):
        file.__init__(self, *args, **keyws)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(os.fstat(self.fileno())[6])


def b2_upload_file(self, file_name, file_content):
    file_contents = file_content.read()
    tup = tempfile.mkstemp() # make a tmp file
    f = os.fdopen(tup[0], 'w') # open the tmp file for writing
    f.write(file_contents) # write the tmp file
    f.close()

    ### return the path of the file
    filepath = tup[1] # get the filepath
    data_file = EnhancedFile(filepath, 'rb')

    sha1_of_file_data = hashlib.sha1(file_contents).hexdigest()
    content_type = getattr(file_contents, 'content_type',mimetypes.guess_type(file_name)[0] or self.key_class.DefaultContentType)
    headers = {
        'Authorization' : self.upload_auth_token,
        'X-Bz-File-Name' :  file_name,
        'Content-Type' : content_type,
        'X-Bz-Content-Sha1' : sha1_of_file_data
    }

    request = urllib2.Request(self.upload_url, data_file, headers)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    response_data = json.loads(response.read())
    response.close()
    file_id = response_data['fileId']
    return file_id

def _save(self, name, content):
    self.b2_authorize_account()
    self.b2_get_upload_url()
    file_id = self.b2_upload_file(name, content)
    return file_id
```

However this is really dirty, so if anyone can offer any other advice so that a temp file is not required, I'd be most interested to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Using the BlackBlaze python directory [pusher](https://docs.backblaze.com/public/b2_src_code_bundles/b2_python_pusher) for reference and assuming that `file_content` is a file-like object (like Django's `UploadedFile`), I'd suggest you try passing the file-like object `file_content` rather than string `file_contents` to the `urllib2.Request` constructor.

Relevant bits from the file I linked are:

```
class OpenUrl(object):
    """
    Context manager that handles an open urllib2.Request, and provides
    the file-like object that is the response.
    """

    def __init__(self, url, data, headers):
        self.url = url
        self.data = data
        self.headers = headers
        self.file = None

    def __enter__(self):
        try:
            request = urllib2.Request(self.url, self.data, self.headers)
            self.file = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            return self.file
        except urllib2.HTTPError as e:
            pass # edited
```

and

```
def post_file(url, headers, file_path):
    """Posts the contents of the file to the URL.

    URL-encodes all of the data in the headers before sending.
    """
    with open(file_path, 'rb') as data_file:
        if 'Content-Length' not in headers:
            headers['Content-Length'] = str(os.path.getsize(file_path))
        encoded_headers = dict(
            (k, b2_url_encode(v)) for (k, v) in headers.iteritems()
        )
        with OpenUrl(url, data_file, encoded_headers) as response_file:
            json_text = response_file.read()
            return json.loads(json_text)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting involved. This is how I had it setup initially and it gives me a 400 from BackBlaze. Presumably because `file_content 
<FieldFile: fools_gold.wav>` Somehow I need to pull the file from the filefield and pass just that, not the whole filefield object, which I assume is what is being passed now.

Comment: I don't think so, if that's how their uploader works. One thing the code you posted is missing and the docs says it's required is the `Content-Length
` header ...